# GNOME desktop environment not starting

Tags: gnome, login, lightdm, xserver, ubuntu-mate

I recently moved from Unity to the Ubuntu MATE desktop environment. I was trying to install the GNOME desktop environment.

I followed the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

During installation of `gnome-shell`, I selected `lightdm`.

Also, most of the Unity packages were removed during `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` installation. And I also ran

```
sudo apt-get remove unity unity-asset-pool unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon unity-gtk-module-common unity-lens* unity-services unity-settings-daemon unity-webapps* unity-voice-service
sudo apt-get remove -- purge ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I logged out from the MATE environment and selected the GNOME environment at the login greeter screen. However, after that nothing happens. The login screen is removed, but the GNOME environment does not start.
Is there any step I missed, or is there some problem with the display managers, or graphics?

I have Ubunutu 14.04.03 LTS on Acer V5-571G.

Comment: I could never get lightdm to work. GNOME, by default, doesn't use lightdm...Instead, it uses gdm3 by default, but since this question was asked 6 years ago, you might have been using Ubuntu 16, which is very different.